# Route parameter passing error : Laravel+Vue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, routes, laravel-5.7

I am using `Laravel 5.7` and `Vue.js 2`.

I want to test Vue.js route parameters. But it is not working!!

**app.js**:

```
import ProductDetails from './components/front/shop/ProductDetails'

const routes = [
{
    path: '/pds/:id',
    component: ProductDetails
}
```

**ProductDetails.vue**

```
<template>
    <h1>Book {{ $route.params.id }} </h1>
</template>
```

When I started testing in `localhost:8000/pds/1` ***Page not Found*** is coming. reasons needed for this error.

Comment: is the router configured to use history mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure your backend. See [here](https://laravel-news.com/using-vue-router-laravel)

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/{any}', 'SpaController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```